# file does not name a type error on compilation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write to an output file using the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream file;
file.open ("output.txt");
file.close();
```

When i try to compile I get the error file does not name a type but i clearly state it is ofstream on the line right before it. I'm not sure what's missing here. I've looked on forums for how to output to a file and this is the code given.

Comment: Presumably the last three lines are inside a function?  If yes, then it should compile fine: http://ideone.com/w4E0tK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file.open ("output.txt");
file.close();
```

These are statements which have to be inside a function. In C++ oonly declarations can go in the globals scope. Try something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream file;
    file.open ("output.txt");
    file.close();
}
```

Which puts your code into a `main` function, which is called on program start.